# Multiple hypothesis testing using replicate data in R

Tags: r, testing, sample

In the following data frame, I want to calculate p-values for each protein comparing the 'control' replicates and the 'treated' replicates. I am very new to using R and I just want to see if I can shift away from using Excel for tasks like these. In reality, I'll have thousands of proteins. I'll then use `p.adjust()` to correct for the multiple hypothesis testing.

I'd be very grateful for any advice.

```
Protein Control_1 Control_2 Control_3 Treated_1 Treated_2 Treated_3
1       1      7.15      7.16      7.11      6.91      6.88      6.92
2       2      6.64      6.61      6.59      6.37      6.35      6.41
3       3      3.68      3.78      3.81      2.40      2.09      2.17
4       4      5.04      5.01      4.69      3.43      3.52      3.66
5       5      6.92      6.81      6.90      7.12      7.21      7.27
```

Desired: -

```
Protein Control_1 Control_2 Control_3 Treated_1 Treated_2 Treated_3 P-value
1       1      7.15      7.16      7.11      6.91      6.88      6.92      0.000413
2       2      6.64      6.61      6.59      6.37      6.35      6.41      0.000742
3       3      3.68      3.78      3.81      2.40      2.09      2.17      0.001010
4       4      5.04      5.01      4.69      3.43      3.52      3.66      0.001262
5       5      6.92      6.81      6.90      7.12      7.21      7.27      0.004306
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated with @StupidWolf's comment.

Since you are new to R I am providing an easy to understand and modify solution.

```
# Generate data that looks like yours
df <-  data.frame(Protein=1:5,Control_1=rnorm(5,5),Control_2=rnorm(5,5),
           Control_3=rnorm(5,5),Treated_1=rnorm(5,5),Treated_2=rnorm(5,5),
           Treated_3=rnorm(5,5))
p_vals <- rep(NA,nrow(df))
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  i.p_val <- t.test(df[i,grep("Control",colnames(df))],
                    df[i,grep("Treated",colnames(df))])$p.value
  p_vals[i] <- i.p_val
}
df <- cbind(df,Pvalue=p_vals)
df
```

should give you

```
  Protein Control_1 Control_2 Control_3 Treated_1 Treated_2 Treated_3    Pvalue
1       1  5.813581  5.149145  4.662203  5.481839  6.424654  5.503664 0.2621811
2       2  4.191440  6.155372  5.773128  3.941712  5.945056  4.182457 0.4769504
3       3  4.654504  4.598808  5.258675  4.101895  6.135411  4.276641 0.9993112
4       4  5.426672  4.520739  6.293757  3.787395  5.274740  3.847900 0.1909877
5       5  5.614929  6.993289  3.786346  5.193352  5.362928  4.746676 0.7353676
```

You can change it from `t.test()` to other tests like non-parametric ones if you like.

Comment: You can initialize the Pvalue column in the df first, i.e df$Pvalue <- NA.. and you start filling in the p values. I appreciate you are writing this for someone new to R, but growing a vector with c().. can be quite bad for large data.frames

Comment: see growing objects under https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf

Comment: Agreed @StupidWolf. Updating with your suggestion

Comment: Hi JustGettingStarted and StupidWolf! I just tried it now and it worked really well! The p.adjust() worked afterwards too! Many thanks for your help with this! Adam, UK.